# How to Create a Poké Stop on Pokémon GO

Tags: pokemon-go

Is this possible?

According to [this post](http://toucharcade.com/2016/07/14/how-to-make-new-pokestop-pokemon-go/) there is (or used to be) a way to submit a request for a Poké Stop.

Looking at the [request page](https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=319928) linked there is no option for this any more.

[image]

Was this request removed or is the information in the linked post incorrect?

Comment: @Kaizerwolf That links the same page I have in my question.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. It's still a dupe nonetheless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a possibility to *request* a Pokéstop for a short time. You were never able to actively create one (like your question's title indicates). 
The request feature probably got overrun, so they took it out of the menu again.